# string search in javascript not able to find the present string 

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

This works :

```
var str ='<input id="a_49519498" type="radio" name="answers[10903336]" value="49519498" />cat,dog       ';

if(str.search('cat,dog')!=-1)
    {
    alert("found ");
    }
```

While this does not :

```
var str ='<input id="a_49519498" type="radio" name="answers[10903336]" value="49519498" />Rock (Foreigner, Nickelback, etc...)       ';

if(str.search('Rock (Foreigner, Nickelback, etc...)')!=-1)
    {
    alert("found ");
    }
```

​I am guessing that this has something to do with the brackets that are present in

> (Foreigner, Nickelback, etc...)

Why is JavaScript unable to find this string ? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems [`.search` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) converts the argument into a regular expression:

> If a non-RegExp object `obj` is passed, it is implicitly converted to a `RegExp` by using `new RegExp(obj)`.

The parenthesis are then interpreted as capture group and not taken literally.

It seems you don't want to use regular expressions, so you could just use [`.indexOf`  *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead:

```
if(str.indexOf('Rock (Foreigner, Nickelback, etc...)') != -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do add escapes before your paranthesis, normally it would be 1 paranthesis, but in this case the `()` create a **group** so we need to use `\\` two.

```
\\(
\\)

str.search('Rock \\(Foreigner, Nickelback, etc...\\)')
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wevtk/)

Comment: i can't add those i am dynamically extracting the data from a webpage

Comment: You need to simply look through look through the string before you do your search for `( or )` and replace them with `\\( and \\)` before you do your `.search()`

Answer (score 1):

`String.search` searches for a regular expression, not a string literal (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).  Just escape your parentheses:

```
str.search('Rock \\(Foreigner, Nickelback, etc...\\)'
```